# Input value hidden

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I have this input:

```
<input id="tag1" type="text" name="tags" class="tags" value="@Model.list" />
```

and I want to get this input value in a hidden input, so I used this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="tags" />
```

Instead of getting the true value of the first input, I only get the string "tags"! Can you please  tell me how to obtain the true value of the first input in my hidden input? Thanks!

EDIT: Actually it's a submit page, the user enters tags in the #tag1 and when he clicks on submit I want to send these tags to my controller, that's why I'm using the hidden input...
My full code:

```
<form>
        <p>
        <input id="tag1" type="text" name="tags" class="tags" value="@Model.list" onblur="setValue()"; /></p>
        <script>
            $('#tag1').tagsInput({
                // my parameters here
            });

        </script>
<style>
#wrapper { 
margin: 20px;    
}


</style>



    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        <input type="hidden" name="taggg" id="tag2" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setValue() {

                document.getElementById("tag2").value = document.getElementById("tag1").value;
            }

            window.onload = setValue;
        </script>


    </p>


    </form>
```

Comment: With some JavaScript I guess. Have a go at it. But why do you want that? Isn't that just going to be the same?

Comment: what is your interpretation of *hidden*? do you mean password-like or do you mean the input field must be invisible?

Comment: u need to use Javascript.. u have given value as tags to the input type=hidden.. obviously u will get what value u have given for that hidden input.. use javascript and u can assign value to the hidden input field...

Comment: did the answers provided below solve your problem? if you want the hidden field to have the true value of first input only on submit, call the function in the submit button's `onclick` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you would want to copy the value of one input field to another (albeit, hidden). But if that is what you want to do, try using the below code.

The function attached to the `onblur` event of the input field would set the value of the input field to the hidden field whenever it loses focus.

The `window.onload = setValue` will do the same on page load.

**HTML**

```
<input id="tag1" type="text" name="tags" class="tags" value="@Model.list" onblur="setValue();" />
<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="tags" id="tag1_hidden" /> <!-- Note the addition of an id attribute -->
```

**JavaScript**

```
function setValue() {
    document.getElementById("tag1_hidden").value = document.getElementById("tag1").value;
}

window.onload = setValue;
```

Comment: Thank you! the first input #tag1 is a Jquery Tags Input (http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/) so when the page loads, there are 5 tags in the input (@Model.list). The user has the possibility of removing current tags or adding new ones. The problem is everytime, in the hidden input #tag2 I get the @Model.list even if the user removed all the tags and inserted new ones! any idea why the #tag1 value doesnt change and is always @Model.list? Thank you so much Harry :)

Comment: Have you called the function on `onsubmit` of the form or on `onblur` of the input field as indicated in my answer? Can I have a look at your full code? Any link?

Comment: I called the onblur only, the code is very long, but I will show you only this part in the Edit above :)

Comment: Harry I added the onlick event to the submit button and it worked! Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this (and you will need javascript for this).

Give a id to your hidden input also like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_input" name="tag" value="tags" />
```

and then use/paste this code when you need it:

```
var input_value = document.getElementById('tag1').value;
document.getElementById('hidden_input').value = input_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input id="tag1" type="text" name="tags" class="tags" value="@Model.list" />
<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="tags" id="tag2" />
```

Jquery:

```
$("#tag2").val($("#tag1").val());
```

or

```
$("#tag1").blur(function() {
  $("#tag2").val($(this).val());
});
```